# ¿Por qué mi función no se ejecuta cada milisegundo?

Tags: javascript, css, setinterval

Tengo una función que muestra un valor "Tiempo" que aumenta en 1 cada milisegundo y lo muestra en pantalla. También ejecuto otra función que hace cambiar una imagen cada 4 segundos (4000ms) en JavaScript. Si se están ejecutando a la par, ¿por qué cuando muestro el valor del "Tiempo" este es erróneo ya que me muestra un valor menor?

Cada cambio de imagen, "Tiempo" debería ser un múltiplo de 4000.

Solo se muestra bien cuando la llamada la hago cada 10 o 100ms, incluso cada 1000ms, pero con el valor mínimo que sería 1ms no lo hace.

```
var cambiar = setInterval(cambiarImagen, 4000);
var tiempoTranscurrido = setInterval(mostrarTiempo, 1);
```

¿Tiene algo que ver con la capacidad del procesador o algo así?

Gracias.

Comment: Saludos. Eso de "[...] me muestra un valor menor?" no esta muy claro que dices (un ejemplo de lo que debe ocurrir y lo que ocurre); ahora bien, lo que ve el usuario final como estático en una aplicación (escritorio, movil y/o web, etc) no es lo único que esta ocurriendo. Ahora le pides a la aplicación que lleve control y realice X cosa mil veces por segundo y otro proceso cada 4 segundos, no me parece raro si lo que se ve es un retraso incluso bloqueo.

Comment: ¿Qué sentido tiene ejecutar código cada milisegundo? De hecho ¿qué sentido tiene mostrar el tiempo en milisegundos en una aplicación web? Tal vez usar centésimas de segundo bastaría para dar algún efecto visual, ¿pero milisegundos? No hay visión humana capaz de ver el cambio de las centésimas de segundo, menos las milésimas. Me atrevo a decir que sólo con mostrar décimas es más que suficiente. Es una opinión, claro está.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eso ocurre porque cada navegador tiene un minimo de tiempo establecido, Chrome parece que son 4 ms y en Firefox 5ms, tal vez ya haya cambiado con el tiempo, por tanto lo ideal es que utilices un valor superior al mínimo de los navegadores para que garantices funcione igual,

si fijas un valor inferior al mínimo o lo estableces en 0 el resultado puede no ser el deseado

***Fuente de donde saque que el minimo es 4ms - 5ms***

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout#Reasons_for_delays_longer_than_specified

---

También considera que ejecutar una función cada 1ms vas a reventar la maquina por el consumo de memoria., el procesador no creo que tenga problemas pero si la memoria del equipo.

Comment: Alguna fuente que corrobore lo primero que mencionas?

Comment: Servido, deje un enlace para referencia

Comment: Agradezco tu respuesta, responde precisamente a la duda que tenía.